# Apache Nifi append function

Tags: apache-nifi

$.id:append('-') & ${id:append('-')} in Evaluate JsonPathProcessor gives me no results, what would we be the correct way to append a text at the end of an incoming attribute in Apache Nifi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Apache NiFi had a sample input JSON document like:

```
{
  "id": "foo"
}
```

Then you can extract and format attributes in two steps:

1. [EvaluateJsonPath](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.2.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.EvaluateJsonPath/index.html) to extract a value from the input JSON document to a NiFi flowfile attribute. For the sample, you might add a custom property `json.id` with the JsonPath of `$.id`.  A flowfile attribute called `json.id` will be added to the flowfile with the value `foo`.
   [image]
2. [UpdateAttribute](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-update-attribute-nar/1.2.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.attributes.UpdateAttribute/index.html) to use NiFi Expression Language to format the id.  You can assign any attribute, like `formatted.id` using an expression that references the attribute extracted earlier, `json.id`:
   [image]